unable to access the components of p dialog in primefaces
I am using prime-faces and want to integrate 2 pages for that I used tab view to show the 2 pages in a single page using tabs.
one of my pages has a p dialog panel, when I implement tab view I am facing an accessibility issue, the dialog is opening but the dialog components are not accessible like before.
i am tried to keep the dialog outside of tab view and inside of form but still issue persist, please help me how to fix this i am out of my ways.
JSF Code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<body>
  <ui:composition  template="/template/layout.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="body">
  <h:form id="demo-list-form">
 <h:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%">
 <p:tabView styleClass="full-width-tabview" >
 <p:tab title="tab1">
 <h:panelGrid id ="custom_query_panel">
        <p:commandButton id="custom_dialog" value="custom Query" type="button"  onclick="rc()" />
 </h:panelGrid>
 <p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="message" action="#{demoBean.resetMessage}" oncomplete="demoCustomQuery.show();"/>

 <p:dialog id="customQueryDlg" header="custom Queries" dynamic="true"   widgetVar="demoCustomQuery" resizable="true" modal="true" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip" >
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:commandButton id="delete" value="Delete" style="float:left;" action="#{demoBean.deleteQuery}" update="customtable message">
               </p:commandButton>
               <h:outputText id="message" value="#{demoBean.message}" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"/>

        </h:panelGrid>
        <t:dataTable headerClass="dialogTableHeader" id="customtable" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2"  rowClasses="oddRows, evenRows" var="demo" value="#{demoBean.savedQueryList}" >

                <t:column width="25">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="checkAll(this)"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{demoBean.selectedQueryName[demo.name]}"/>
                </t:column>

                <t:column width="150">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Query Name"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{demo.name}"/>
                </t:column>

                <t:column width="750">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="query details"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{demo.query}" />
                </t:column>

                <t:column width="90">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Apply"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:commandButton value="Apply" action="#{demoBean.viewCustomReport}" style="color:blue;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold}">
                                <f:param name="queryname" value="#{demo.name}" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                </t:column>
        </t:dataTable>
   </p:dialog>
 </p:tab>
 <p:tab title="tab2">
 <h:outputText id="message" value="demo tab 2" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"/>
 </p:tab>
 </p:tabView>
 </h:panelGrid>
 </h:form>
 </ui:define>
 </ui:composition>
 </body>
 </html>

screen shot:


The description of the problem "components are not accessible" is very ambiguous and based on the screenshot it appears that you basically meant to say that the ajax loading overlay gets stuck and doesn't disappear after it's finished, and therefore the webpage is not interactable by the enduser, right? Have you looked in the JavaScript console in the web developer's toolset (press F12) for any clues? This symptom is usually consequence of an uncaught error/exception in JS context which is in turn usually caused by a typo/syntax/logic error in JS.

yes i checked for errors in the console but not found anything
